# Safari remote debugging doesn't see iPhone

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios13

I connected my iPhone (iOS 13) to MacBook through cable with small USB->USB-C adapter. iPhone showed in Debug tab, I tried use it but there was problem with connection.

MacOS wanted download some update to connect with my iPhone. I downloaded it and setup iTunes (i just bought iPhone and it was my first attempt to connecting phone to MacBook). After installation iPhone disappeared from Develop options and I can't bring it back.

Maybe there is problem with my adapter? It isn't from apple.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double-check the config. Maybe after the update, the config was set back to default

https://support.brightcove.com/debugging-mobile-devices

It's not. Maybe from your adapter. But you don't need use a adapter from Apple because I use a third party one like https://tiki.vn/hub-usb-typec-8-cong-hdmiusb-30sdtflan-gigabit-rj45-ugreen-50538-hang-chinh-hang-p6734149.html still work

Comment: So just change the adapter to try :(

Comment: Or may the issue from your cable. Is it from Apple ?

Comment: Yes, it's from charger